# Get rid of IE download warning

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a web-page with complicated form. Also, there is a button "preview", which is using jquery to collect form data, post it to server, the server generates .rtf or .txt document and returns a link to created file to client. Afterwards, I need user to automaticly download this file. To do this, I open this received link programmaticly in callback function.
Everything works fine, except for IE7-8, in which the security bar appears, preventing download (which is unacceptable, due to it will refresh the form). I assume this happens because of "non-active click", but I cannot figure out how to get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: How exactly are you successfully forcing a download through javascript on other browsers?

Comment: How long does generating the file take? Just return the file with an appropriate content type and content-disposition:attachment

Comment: emm, it is possible to return binary content through the $.post callback function?

Comment: >How exactly are you successfully forcing a download through >javascript on other browsers
Well, I'm not exactly forcing, but just a download dialog appear, which is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is security concern, and it **should** be there, to prevent scripted download of files, without confirmation of user.

Don't generate *.rtf/*.txt files for preview, use HTML to preview. When user will want *.rtf/*.txt, he will download it, when you want just a preview, use WYSIWYG editor, to handle documents, like *Google documents* does.

Comment: My bad, I was unaccurate when describing the situation. Actualy, it is a requirement to generate the file, although it's obviously a bad pattern.